# Find unique pairings of entries in a character vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, unique

I have a vector `fruit` with three entries `Peach, Plum, Pear`. I would like to find each unique pairing in `fruit` and create a new, two column data.frame (e.g. df.new below). How might I do this in r for an even larger data.set? `expand.grid` results in `pear-plum` and `plum-pear` which are not unique pairings, or not the ones I am seeking. Any suggestions?

```
fruit <- c("Peach", "Plum", "Pear")

fruit1 <- c("Peach", "Peach", "Plum")
fruit2 <- c("Plum", "Pear", "Pear")
df.new <- data.frame(fruit1, fruit2)

#df.new
fruit1 fruit2
1  Peach   Plum
2  Peach   Pear
3   Plum   Pear

# attempt
fruit.y <- fruit
df.expand <- expand.grid(fruit,fruit.y)
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for `?combn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your initial strategy, you can still try expand grid:

`fruit_df <- expand.grid(fruit,fruit)`

Then sort each row by fruit and delete the duplicates:

`fruit_df2 <- as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(fruit_df, 1, function(x) sort(x)))))`

```
     V1    V2
1 Peach Peach
2 Peach  Plum
3 Peach  Pear
4  Plum  Plum
5  Pear  Plum
6  Pear  Pear
```

Another strategy is to generate all combination of pairs in `fruit`, try:

`combn(fruit,2)`

```
     [,1]    [,2]    [,3]  
[1,] "Peach" "Peach" "Plum"
[2,] "Plum"  "Pear"  "Pear"
```

Or to make your output as a data frame, transpose the results and recast:

`as.data.frame(t(combn(fruit,2)))`

Note that using `combn` you will not get the `plum-plum`.

Comment: In both approaches above the results includes `same-same` is there a way to not include these pairings aside from `subset(fruit_df, ! fruit_df$Var1 == fruit_df$Var2)` ?

Comment: @nofunsally my original post had an error -- using the `combn` approach you will not get duplicate pairs like `same-same`. i've corrected the error.