# Calculate differences between unique pairings of data.frame variables

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply, difference

I have a data.frame `data`:

```
Sector Var1 Var2 Var3
Abcd    1    1    1
Efgh    4    5    6
Ijkl    7    8    9
```

I would like to create a new data.frame that consists of the difference between each unique pairing of `Sector` for each variable. An example of the desired result is below:

```
# result
Sector1 Sector2 Dif_Var1 Dif_Var2 Dif_Var3
Abcd    Efgh        3        4        5
Abcd    Ijkl        6        7        8
Efgh    Ijkl        3        3        3
```

I can find each unique pair (code below) for `Sector` but am unsure if this is the way to proceed. Is this minimal pseudo code below seem like an appropriate and potentially successful route?

```
# pseudo code
result <- which(Sector1 == Sector) get Var1,2,3 values - which(Sector2 == Sector) get Var1,2,3 values
```

Is there an r function or package that would facilitate arriving at the desired result?

```
# unique pairings
# http://stackoverflow.com/q/23024059/1670053
df <- structure(list(Sector = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Abcd", "Efgh", 
"Ijkl"), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(1L, 4L, 7L), Var2 = c(1L, 
5L, 8L), Var3 = c(1L, 6L, 9L)), .Names = c("Sector", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df.u <- expand.grid(df$Sector,df$Sector)
df.u2 <- as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(df.u, 1, function(x) sort(x)))))
data <- subset(df.u2, ! df.u2$V1 == df.u2$V2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sqldf package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select A.Sector Sector1,
              B.Sector Sector2,
              B.Var1 - A.Var1 Var1, 
              B.Var2 - A.Var2 Var2, 
              B.Var3 - A.Var3 Var3
              from df A join df B
              on A.Sector < B.Sector")
```

giving:

```
  Sector1 Sector2 Var1 Var2 Var3
1    Abcd    Efgh    3    4    5
2    Abcd    Ijkl    6    7    8
3    Efgh    Ijkl    3    3    3
```

This could also be written:

```
 nms <- names(df)[-1]
 sel <- toString( sprintf('B.%s - A.%s %s', nms, nms, nms) )
 fn$sqldf("select A.Sector Sector1, B.Sector Sector2, $sel 
           from df A join df B 
           on A.Sector < B.Sector")
```

**REVISED** Fixed and added variation.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `V1` and `V2` vectors that you created to index `df`

```
df[data$V2, -1] - df[data$V1, -1]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
#2      3    4    5
#3      6    7    8
#3.1    3    3    3
```

keeping the names

```
cbind(data$V1, data$V2, df[data$V2, -1] - df[data$V1, -1])
#    data$V1 data$V2 Var1 Var2 Var3
#2      Abcd    Efgh    3    4    5
#3      Abcd    Ijkl    6    7    8
#3.1    Efgh    Ijkl    3    3    3
```